# URL rewrite issue wih IE - causing it to append

Tags: internet-explorer, url, url-rewriting

I have the following URL rewrite similar to

```
RewriteRule   ^event/([0-9]+)/$   page1.php?title=$1   [NC,L]

RewriteRule   ^view/([0-9]+)/$    page2.php?id=$1      [NC,L]
```

When I go to `domain.com/app/event/3/` - it goes to the correct URL.

In this page, I have a JavaScript which has the following `onclick` event

```
location.href = "view/5/";
```

In all the browsers this translated as `domain.com/app/view/5/`. But in IE (both 8 as well as 9) it end up as `domain.com/app/event/3/view/5/`

It just seems to append to the previous URL.

Answer (score 0):

IE appears to be behaving as expected. Relative paths in your `href` should be interpreted as being relative to the current path, since the markup has no knowledge of how things are structured on your server-side, unless of course you tell it.

The *issue* you're having happens for me in Chrome as well, as it should. If you want relative urls to be resolved based on a base path, you need to either provide that in your `href` from the beginning, or provide it via a `<base>` tag in your `<head>`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/app/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="event/7">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="event/6">Bar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above will work as expected because we have instructed the browser to resolve any relative paths based on the `href` of the `<base>` element in the `<head>` section. If you do not do this, the browser is expected to resolve the relative `href` of any `<a>` relative to the current path.

Pay special attention to [this portion](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4.1) of the spec regarding relative-urls:

> User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following precedences (highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. The base URI is set by the BASE element.
> 2. The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [RFC2616]).
> 3. **By default, the base URI is that of the current document**. Not all HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may appear in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML documents are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and rely on a default base URI. (emphasis added)

So again, if you wish to see relative `href` values resolve to your base url, you need to provide that base either in the link itself, or via the `<base>` element as I have done in the example above.

### Additional Things to Consider:

I wanted to return to this question and document some other things to consider that may be relevant. Various methods of accessing the `href` attribute of an anchor return different results.

Consider the following:

```js
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.setAttribute("href", "foo.php?fizz=buzz");

console.log( "href:         " + anchor.href );
console.log( "getAttribute: " + anchor.getAttribute("href") );
```

Here is the output we see for various versions of Internet Explorer:

**Internet Explorer 6 - 7**:

```
href:         foo.php?fizz=buzz
getAttribute: foo.php?fizz=buzz
```

**Internet Explorer 8 - 10**:

```
href:         http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/foo.php?fizz=buzz
getAttribute: foo.php?fizz=buzz
```

Since Internet Explorer 8, the `.href` property automatically resolves a full URI based on the current document location, appending the anchor's `href` value onto the end. This is the same behavior we see in other modern browsers.

For this reason, if you need to grab *only* the `href` value, it's wise to use `.getAttribute("href")` instead of accessing the `.href` property.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for the reply. I forgot to mention that I do have a base path in the header: `<base href="http://<?= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/apps/eventmanager/" />`. Still IE8/9 refuses to respect it

Comment: I have isolated the problem to javascript. If I use the anchor tag with href <a data-lang='ar' href="event/2/lang/ar/">Ar</a>, then it works fine. However if I have a jquery click event where the location.href is set to event/2/lang/ar/ then it instead goes to /event/2/event/2/lang/ar - as you can see the url is appended to previous URL. This happens only in IE.

Comment: @JesbinBaidya What is the actual `<base>` tag you're using; after the PHP is processed.

Comment: JOnathan, I am using something like <base href="http://<?= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/apps/eventmanager/" />

Comment: @JesbinBaidya I understand, but what is the final output that is showing up in your HTML?

Comment: The final url I see in the generated html is `<base href="http://www-dev.wmo.int/apps/eventmanager/" />`

Comment: Thanks you @JonathanSampson, I had the same problem in Chrome, but the <base href="/"> tag solved my problem